# fragment crashing after rotate

Tags: android, sqlite

the app loads fine on either mode (vertical/horizontal) but when rotating it crash.

I am using sqlit so before I start the fragment, using a setter, I set its Cursor variable and than I start it.
from what I saw when debugging even though the setter was "working" the fragment crashed later because its Cursor was null

main activity

```java
db=new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Fragment fragment = new gallery();
        ((gallery) fragment).setmCursor(db.getAll());

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment_layout,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you rotate your app, the activity goes out of scope temporarily.  This can set many of the local variables to null.  I typically create a method called RestoreAll().  In this method, I inflate all my textboxes, buttons etc. and re-initialize them.  I also call to create any list arrays or database cursors that I need to create lists from.  I call RestoreAll() from the onResume() method.  onResume gets called right after the onCreate() method, the first time the activity is loaded.  Then, if the screen is rotated, onResume() gets called again, so, this will call RestoreAll() again.  Not everything will have been set to null, but this is an easy way to ensure that everything gets repopulated whenever the activity resumes.